# Failed to load external entity on simplexml_load_file at Openstreetmap

Tags: php, xml, openstreetmap, nominatim

I recently checked one of our websites and realized that the search for postal code wasn't working anymore.

I get the following error:

> 'Failed to load external entity'

If instead I use `simplexml_load_string()` I  receive

> 'Start tag expected, '<' not found'.

This is the code I'm using:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?postalcode=28217&country=DE&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&boundary=postalcode');
if (false === $xml) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    var_dump($errors);
}
```

I read somewhere it might actually has something to do with HTTP headers but I did not find any useful info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSM Nominatim's usage policy it is stated that you need to provide a `User-Agent` or `HTTP-Referer` request header to identify the application. As such, using a user-agent to masquerade as end-user browser is really not great etiquette.

You can find the usage policy [here](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). It also says that the default values used by http libraries (like the one `simplexml_load_file()` uses) are not acceptable.

You say you are using `simplexml_load_string()`, but fail to say how are you getting the XML to that function. But the most likely scenario is that whichever method you are using to get the XML file, you are also neglecting to pass the mandatory headers.

As such, I'd create a request using [php-curl](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.curl.php), provide one of these headers to identify your app; and parse the resulting XML string with `simplexml_parse_string()`.

E.g.:

```
// setup variables
$nominatim_url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?postalcode=28217&country=DE&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&boundary=postalcode';
$user_agent    = 'ID_Identifying_Your_App v100';
$http_referer  = 'http://www.urltoyourapplication.com';
$timeout       = 10;

// curl initialization
$ch         = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $nominatim_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

// this is are the bits you are missing
// Setting curl's user-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
// you an also use this one (http-referer), it's up to you. Either one or both.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $http_referer); 

// get the XML
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// load it in simplexml
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
// This was your code, left as it was
if (false === $xml) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    var_dump($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can useing `curl`with adding custom header , i hope this code useful for you :

```
<?php
$request_url='https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?postalcode=28217&country=DE&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&boundary=postalcode';

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,und;q=0.7',
'User-Agent:    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo($data);
```